# In Illustrator, file is completely different than in Acrobat

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

Today, I was making a map of an interchange point for a local transit company, and I had been basically finished, but for some reason the file started completely freaking out.

I exported a finished .pdf, but for some reason, that same file opens as an unfinished, two hours old version of that file.

When I try to export this unfinished .pdf that I opened in Illustrator to a new .pdf, the exported file is the finished version.

The cycle can go on and on and there's nothing I can do - the .pdf opened in Illustrator is the finished one, the .pdf opened in Illustrator is always the unfinished one. This means that while I do have the product, I cannot edit it further, which is a problem.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Copy all primitives over to a new file and save it under a different name.

Comment: Acrobat does this at times. Quit and relaunch Acrobat and try again.. if it's still a problem, reboot the machine (seriously.)